# Android - How to generate random numbers and set those numbers on TextViews

Tags: android

I got a button and five TextViews. On click I want to generate random numbers from 1 to 70 and display results into TextViews. Numbers in TextViews should not be the same.

Currently I got this code which generate only one number in one TextView.

```
public void generate(View view) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number =  rand.nextInt(69)+1;

        TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String myString = String.valueOf(number);
        myText.setText(myString);
    }
```

Comment: why dont you replicate the code 5 times? Taking one textview each time?

Comment: Why do you have a View object as parameter when you don't use it?

Comment: `rand.nextInt(6)+1` will return values in [1,6], not in [1, 70]

Comment: with the edit, your code generate random numbers between 1 and 69 not 70

Comment: Can the numbers of two textviews be the same if two random number by coincidence are the same?

Comment: the quality of comments and answers here are really low.  Create a separate method that sets the value of a given `TextView`. then call it 5 times. You have done most the work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List` and add generated random numbers to it, if the numbers are not already in that list

```
    List<Integer> myNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (true) {
        int number = rand.nextInt(69) + 1;
        if (!myNumbers.contains(number)) {
            myNumbers.add(number);

            if (myNumbers.size() == 5)
                break;
        }
    }

    text1.setText(myNumbers.get(0));
    text2.setText(myNumbers.get(1));
    text3.setText(myNumbers.get(2));
    text4.setText(myNumbers.get(3));
    text5.setText(myNumbers.get(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give number between 1 to 70

```
Random r = new Random();
    int lowRange = 1;
    int highRange = 70;
    int result = r.nextInt(highRange -lowRange ) + lowRange ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `Arraylist`. Try something like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) number.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
TextView text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);

    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    text4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    text5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    yourClickEventHere
}

public void generate(View view){
    for(int i = 0; i< 5 ; i++){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number =  rand.nextInt(69)+1;
        switch i{
            case 0:
                String myString = String.valueOf(number);
                text1.setText(myString);
                break;
            case 1:
                String myString = String.valueOf(number);
                text2.setText(myString);
                break;
            case 2:
                String myString = String.valueOf(number);
                text3.setText(myString);
                break;
            case 3:
                String myString = String.valueOf(number);
                text4.setText(myString);
                break;
            case 4:
                String myString = String.valueOf(number);
                text5.setText(myString);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to get unique numbers

```
private HashSet<Integer> getUniqueNumbers(){
        HashSet<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>(5);
        while (numbers.size() < 5) {
            int number = new Random().nextInt(69) + 1;
            numbers.add(number);
        }
        return numbers;
    }
```

More generic way:

```
private HashSet<Integer> getUniqueNumbers(int range, int size){
        HashSet<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>(size);
        while (numbers.size() < size) {
            int number = new Random().nextInt(range-1) + 1;
            numbers.add(number);
        }
        return numbers;
    }
```

Call:

```
getUniqueNumbers(70, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way. I believe this is what you want.

```
ublic class RandomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int viewCount = 5;

        LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
        root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
            TextView v = generate();
            root.addView(v);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        setContentView(root);
    }

    static List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        for (int i = 1; i < 70; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
    }


    public TextView generate() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = numbers.remove(rand.nextInt(numbers.size()));

        TextView myText = new TextView(this);
        String myString = String.valueOf(number);
        myText.setText(myString);
        return myText;
    }
}
```